# Are Snackbar Components available in Android L preview sdk?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

Snackbars were components in the [material design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-and-toasts.html#snackbars-and-toasts-usage). I am implementing snack bar for android L but I found it as a library. Is it available in android L preview sdk? Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not available as part of the SDK, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25828111/1232023

Comment: With the design support library the Snackbar is finally officially released: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520625/how-to-use-the-snackbar-of-android-design-support-library/30522882#30522882

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be a `Snackbar` implementation in the current "L" Developer Preview. At least, one does not appear in [the JavaDocs for the "L" Developer Preview](http://developer.android.com/preview/reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Snackbars support was recently added to Android Support Library revision 22.2.0: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html