# What are the new features of Android Design Support Library and how to use its Snackbar?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-snackbar

Android M Preview for developers was released yesterday. As usual, many amazing  new features are introduced. I noticed that `Snackbar` is one of them.

I have read the document about `Snackbar`, from which I learnt that Snackbar is in the library of Android Design Support Library, whose absolute path is [`android.support.design.widget.Snackbar`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html).

And the document says that:

> Snackbars provide lightweight feedback about an operation. They show
>   a brief message at the bottom of the screen on mobile and lower left
>   on larger devices. Snackbars appear above all other elements on
>   screen and only one can be displayed at a time.
>
> They automatically disappear after a timeout or after user interaction
>   elsewhere on the screen, particularly after interactions that summon a
>   new surface or activity. Snackbars can be swiped off screen.

So, does `Snackbar` behave like a `Toast` or a `Dialog`? Can Snackbars be used in a layout file? How could I use it programmatically?

**P.S.:**

- Any samples on use of Snackbar will be appreciated.
- Android Design Support Library is a new support library, could
  somebody show me more details of this library?

Comment: you can see :https://github.com/MrEngineer13/SnackBar

Comment: or :https://github.com/nispok/snackbar

Comment: I mean the `Snackbar` from `android design support library`. the `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar`

Comment: Chris Banes actually posted a demo for the support library few moments ago https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes/posts/7xPXwAZnndn
Here is the github repo though https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/

Comment: Yes, I found it. `Snackbar.make(view, "Here's a Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();`. Don't be so mean. man.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As for `Snackbar`,it acts like a `Toast` but is different with a `Toast`. **Snackbars** are shown on the bottom of the screen and contain text with an optional single action. They automatically time out after the given time length by animating off the screen. In addition, users can swipe them away before the timeout which is considerably more powerful than toasts, another lightweight feedback mechanism.

You can use it programmatically like this:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
  .make(parentLayout, R.string.snackbar_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
  .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action, myOnClickListener);
snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.CYAN);
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);//change Snackbar's background color;
TextView textView = (TextView)snackbarView .findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);//change Snackbar's text color;
snackbar.show(); // Don’t forget to show!
```

Note the use of a View in the method of `make()` - `Snackbar` will attempt to find it ensure that it is anchored to its bottom.

What's more, **Android Design Support Library** is used for **Android 2.1+ (API 7+)**, which features **navigation drawer view**, **floating labels for editing text**, **floating action button**, **snackbar**, **tabs** and something like that.

**Navigation View**

The navigation drawer can be an important focal point for identity and navigation within your app and consistency in the design here can make a considerable difference in how easy your app is to navigate, particularly for first time users. `NavigationView` makes this easier by providing the framework you need for the navigation drawer as well as the ability to inflate your navigation items through a menu resource.

You can use it like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <!-- your content layout -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As for the drawer menu, it could be:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
        android:title="@string/navigation_item_1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
        android:title="@string/navigation_item_2"/>
</group>
```

or:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_subheader"
    android:title="@string/navigation_subheader">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
            android:title="@string/navigation_sub_item_1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
            android:title="@string/navigation_sub_item_2"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

You’ll get callbacks on selected items by setting a OnNavigationItemSelectedListener using setNavigationItemSelectedListener(). This provides you with the MenuItem that was clicked, allowing you to handle selection events, changed the checked status, load new content, programmatically close the drawer, or any other actions you may want.

**Floating labels for editing text**

Even the humble `EditText` has room to improve in material design. While an `EditText` alone will hide the hint text after the first character is typed, you can now wrap it in a `TextInputLayout`, causing the hint text to become a *floating label* above the `EditText`, ensuring that users never lose context in what they are entering. In addition to showing hints, you can also display an error message below the `EditText` by calling `setError()`.

**Floating Action Button**

A **floating action button** is a round button denoting a primary action on your interface. The Design library’s `FloatingActionButton` gives you a single consistent implementation, by default colored using the `colorAccent` from your theme.

As `FloatingActionButton` extends `ImageView`, you’ll use `android:src` or any of the methods such as `setImageDrawable()` to control the icon shown within the `FloatingActionButton`.

**Tabs**

*top level navigation pattern* is commonly used for organizing different groupings of content. The Design library’s `TabLayout` implements both fixed tabs, where the view’s width is divided equally between all of the tabs, as well as scrollable tabs, where the tabs are not a uniform size and can scroll horizontally.

Tabs can be added programmatically:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = ...;
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
```

If you want to use `ViewPager` for horizontal paging between tabs, you can create tabs directly from your `PagerAdapter’s` `getPageTitle()` and then connect the two together using `setupWithViewPager()`. This ensures that tab selection events update the `ViewPager` and page changes update the selected tab.

**CoordinatorLayout and the app bar**

the Design library introduces `CoordinatorLayout`, a layout which provides an additional level of control over touch events between child views, something which many of the components in the Design library take advantage of. If you try using an AppBarLayout allows your `Toolbar` and other views (such as tabs provided by `TabLayout`) to react to scroll events in a sibling view marked with a ScrollingViewBehavior. Therefore you can create a layout such as:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <! -- Your Scrollable View -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now, as the user scrolls the `RecyclerView`, the `AppBarLayout` can respond to those events by using the children’s scroll flags to control how they enter (scroll on screen) and exit (scroll off screen).

The Design library, AppCompat, and all of the Android Support Library are important tools in providing the building blocks needed to build a modern, great looking Android app without building everything from scratch.

Comment: Really helpful! I've been trying to change Snackbar's text color for a long time!!

Answer (score 54):

The new [`Snackbar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) **doesn't require Android-M**.

It is inside the **new design support library** and you can use it today.

Just update your SDK add this dependency in your code:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

You can use a code like this:

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Here's a Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("Action", null)
        .show();
```

It is like a Toast.

[image]

To **assign an action** you have to set the `OnClickListener`.

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Here's a Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("Action", myOnClickListener)
        .show();
```

If you would like to **change the background** color you can use something like this:

```
 Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Here's a Snackbar",       
                   Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
 View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
 snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(colorId);
 snackbar.show();
```

[image]

If you would like to have some built-in features as the **swipe-to-dismiss** gesture, or the **FAB scrolling** up the snackbar, simply having a [`CoordinatorLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) in your view hierarchy.

Comment: So, the `Snackbar` could be only displayed aligned the bottom of the `view`, how about the top or left of the `view`? And how could I set the `text`'s gravity, like CENTER, or RIGHT?

Comment: It implements the material design, then shows a message at the bottom of the screen on mobile.

Comment: It does however require that the host activity is an AppCompat one.

Comment: And I suggest you to put it in a [CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) for coordinating animations for the FAB etc.

Comment: I can't seem to dismiss the snackbar by sliding it off. Is this a feature of M?

Comment: @JonnyWright if you would like to have a swipe-to-dismiss gesture , use a CoordinatorLayout in your layout.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti is there any way that we can show the SnackBar for infinite time? I mean it should only dismiss when user will click on the action button of the snackbar? I guess i should on increase the time but i put some integer replacing `Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG` it shows that only `Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG` or `Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT`

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal currently there is a bug. You should be able to set a custom duration with the next release.

Answer (score 36):

On `Activity` you can use:

```
String s = "SnackBar"
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), s, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and on `Fragment`:

```
Snackbar.make(getView(), s, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Edit:

For changing background color I use something like this:

```
String s = "SnackBar"
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(getView(), s, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snack.getView();
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); 
snack.show();
```

And for changing text color (despite theme):

```
View view = snack.getView();
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Works like a charm ;-)

Comment: And how could I set the background color or drawable of a `Snackbar`?

Comment: For changing the text color simply use `setActionTextColor()` on _snack_

Comment: ..to clarify, that is for the action text color, not for the snack text itself

Comment: it's a pity Google Devs haven't supported such trivial things like chaning background color in library

Comment: @MateuszJablonski How could I display a `Snackbar` at the top of a screen?

Comment: @SilentKnight I really don't know. Perhaps you should try passing toolbar view as a parameter and try to set different gravity (for reverse animation in opposite to slide-out from bottom)

Comment: plus one for "findViewById(android.R.id.content)"

Answer (score 0):

I set codeding

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(getView(), text, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

View sbView = Global.alert.getView();
sbView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);

TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
textView.setTextSize(30);

Global.alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Snackbar are capable of displaying icons also.

For example : For no network you can show snackbar like this(Just like Gmail does).

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append(" ").setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.snackbar_icon), 0, 1, 0);
    builder.append(" No Network Available");
    Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.co_ordinate), builder, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    snackBar.setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { //Retry Code here 

        }
    });
    snackBar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

have you seen http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html?

it summarizes the whole support lib.

Answer (score 0):

you can also change text color and background of snackbar

```
 Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Text",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                    TextView tv = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorAccent));
                    snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                    snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple to make a snackbar in android for 10 second

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Hello SnackBar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Its Roy", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setDuration(10000)
                    .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .show();
```