# How to set support library snackbar text color to something other than android:textColor?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-snackbar, snackbar

So I've started using the new Snackbar in the Design Support Library, but I found that when you define "android:textColor" in your theme, it applies to the text color of the snackbar. This is obviously a problem if your primary text color is dark.

[image]

Does anyone know a way around this or have advice for how I should color my text?

**EDIT January 2017: (Post-Answer)**

While there are some custom solutions to fix the problem below, it's probably good to provide the correct way to theme Snackbars.

Firstly, you probably shouldn't be defining `android:textColor` in your themes at all (unless you really know the scope of what is using the theme). This sets the text color of basically every view that connects to your theme. If you want to define text colors in your views that are not default, then use `android:primaryTextColor` and reference that attribute in your custom views.

However, for applying themes to `Snackbar`, please reference this quality guide from a third party material doc: http://www.materialdoc.com/snackbar/ (Follow the programmatic theme implementation to have it not rely on an xml style)

For reference:

```
// create instance
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, text, duration);

// set action button color
snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.indigo));

// get snackbar view
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();

// change snackbar text color
int snackbarTextId = android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text;  
TextView textView = (TextView)snackbarView.findViewById(snackbarTextId);  
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.indigo));

// change snackbar background
snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

(You can also create your own custom `Snackbar` layouts too, see the above link. Do so if this method feels too hacky and you want a surely reliable way to have your custom Snackbar last through possible support library updates).

And alternatively, see answers below for similar and perhaps faster answers to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for the solution! the property is actually called `android:textColorPrimary`

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive explanation.

Comment: "you probably shouldn't be defining android:textColor in your themes at all..." that was the key for me, thank you!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I know this has been answered already but the easiest way I found was directly in the make using the `Html.fromHtml` method and a `font` tag

```
Snackbar.make(view, 
       Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#ffffff\">Tap to open</font>").show()
```

Comment: I prefer this solution since it is single line.

Comment: This is not the actual solution of that question. Use:
snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE).show();

Comment: There is/was a bug in the Snackbar setting the color did nothing.  This way works no matter what but may not be the optimal solution for others.

Comment: This requires API level >24.

Answer (score 184):

I found this at [What are the new features of Android Design Support Library and how to use its Snackbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520625/what-is-new-features-of-android-design-support-library-and-how-to-use-its-snackb?rq=1)

This worked for me for changing the text color in a Snackbar.

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snack.getView();
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
snack.show();
```

**UPDATE: ANDROIDX:**
As dblackker points out in the comments, with the new AndroidX support library, code to find the ID of Snackbar TextView changes to:

```
TextView tv = view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.someColor))
```

Comment: Just in case anyone else is futilely searching for a way to change the text size of a Snackbar, this is it!

Comment: snack.getView()?  what is snack object?

Comment: I believe I have got the complete code      View rootView = ((Activity)context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            Snackbar mysnack= Snackbar.make(rootView, Mensaje, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

           View view= mysnack.getView();

            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            mysnack.show();

Comment: FYI, you can do the same with the Action text by using `snackbar_action` instead of `snackbar_text`. See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36800101/293280

Comment: This is a hack at best - what happens when the ID for android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text changes in a future release of the support library?  Is there not some kind of default SnackBar style that can be overridden in styles.xml?

Comment: That ID was indeed changed in a future release of the support library, I'm getting a null pointer now.

Comment: This is not a good answer for future compat.  Answer below is much better, http://stackoverflow.com/a/37309267/346309

Comment: This is actual solution of that question. I was searching for that types of answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do not use this please, it is very insecure.

Comment: Update - with androidx, the id is now as follows:
`snack.view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView`

Answer (score 18):

Created this kotlin extention function i use in my projects:

```
fun Snackbar.setTextColor(color: Int): Snackbar {
    val tv = view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
    tv.setTextColor(color)

    return this
}
```

**Usage like you would expect:**

> Snackbar.make(view,
> R.string.your_string,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setTextColor(Color.WHITE).show()

Comment: Love the simple use of Kotlin extention methods! ;-)

Comment: Use ```com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text``` if you migrate to AndroidX.

Comment: Changed @Rishabh876 :)

Answer (score 16):

Alright so I fixed it by basically reorganizing the way I do text colors.

In my light theme, I set `android:textColorPrimary` to the `normal dark text` I wanted, and I set `android:textColor` to `white`.

I updated all of my text views and buttons to have `android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary".`

So because snackbar draws from `textColor`, I just set all of my other text to `textColorPrimary`.

**EDIT JANUARY 2017: ----------------------------------------------------**

So as the comments say, and as stated in the edited original question above, you should probably not define `android:textColor` in your themes, as this changes the text color of every view inside the theme.

Comment: I've just completed this task, phew, took a while! However, I needed to use "m vai's" method below for my antiquated Preferences activity (using preferences.xml). I think it's left my app's styling far more correctly theme based which is nice. +1

Comment: Not a good solution IMO ,  i wanna keep my actual theme for textview and just change snakbar text color...

Comment: You're not supposed to define `android:textColor` in your theme at all. It's a *style* attribute of `TextView`. If you define it in your *theme* you override text color of every `TextView` or `Button` which doesn't specify its text color in XML. That also happens to be the snackbar message which would normally take color from its dark *theme overlay*.

Answer (score 15):

Hacking on `android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text` is fragile, a better or less hacky way to do that will be:

```
String snackText = getResources().getString(YOUR_RESOURCE_ID);
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder()
    .append(snackText);
ssb.setSpan(
    new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE),
    0,
    snackText.length(),
    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
Snackbar.make(
        getView(),
        ssb,
        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
```

Answer (score 12):

One approach is to use spans:

```
final ForegroundColorSpan whiteSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.white));
SpannableStringBuilder snackbarText = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello, I'm white!");
snackbarText.setSpan(whiteSpan, 0, snackbarText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

Snackbar.make(view, snackbarText, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
```

With spans you can also add several colors and styles inside one Snackbar. Here's a nice guide:

https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/material-design-snackbar-using-the-design-support-library/

Answer (score 10):

If you migrated to androidX use `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text` instead of 
`android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text` for changing color of text on snackbar.

Comment: U deserve a medal.

Comment: @frank17, it was mentioned in several comments here.

Answer (score 9):

Currently *(January 2020)* with
`com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0` and probably also `1.1.0`

Is definitely the best way how to do it by overrides these styles:

```
<item name="snackbarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar</item>
<item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar</item>
<item name="snackbarTextViewStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView</item>
```

If you use a material theme with `.Bridge` at the end, for some reason, neither of these styles are defined. So Snackar will use some legacy layout without these styles.

I found in the source code that both `snackbarButtonStyle` and `snackbarTextViewStyle` must be defined otherwise it will be not used.

Answer (score 7):

If you will migrate your code to AndroidX, the TextView property is now:

```
com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text
```

Answer (score 6):

The only way I see is using `getView()` and cycling through its child. I don't know if it's going to work, and it is bad as it looks. I hope they'll add some API about this issue soon.

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(...);
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) snack.getView();
for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = group.getChildAt(i);
    if (v instanceof TextView) {
        TextView t = (TextView) v;
        t.setTextColor(...)
    }
}
snack.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [**`Snackbar`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Snackbar.md) included in the **Material Components Library** and apply the

- [`setTextColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar#settextcolor) to define the text color
- [`setActionTextColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar#setactiontextcolor) to define the text color used by the action. You can use a color or a color selector
- [`setBackgroundTint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar#setbackgroundtint) to define the background color of the Snackbar

Something like:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "My custom Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);        
snackbar.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.xxxxx));
snackbar.setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.my_selector));
snackbar.setBackgroundTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.xxxx));
snackbar.show();
```

[image]

---

With **Jetpack Compose** you can customize the [**`SnackbarHost`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#SnackbarHost(androidx.compose.material.SnackbarHostState,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1)) defining a custom `Snackbar`

```
    snackbarHost = {
        // reuse default SnackbarHost to have default animation and timing handling
        SnackbarHost(it) { data ->
            Snackbar(
                snackbarData = data,
                contentColor = Yellow,
                actionColor = Red.copy(alpha = 0.9f)
            )
        }
    }
```

[image]

Then just use it:

```
scope.launch {
    scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
        message = "Snackbar text  # ${++clickCount}",
        actionLabel = "Done")
}
```

Comment: Why is this not getting more upvotes? It works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I changed my theme

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

to

```
Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar
```

It worked.Try to use simple theme instead of light or other theme.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library: https://github.com/SandroMachado/restaurant

```
new Restaurant(MainActivity.this, "Snackbar with custom text color", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
    .show();
```

Disclaimer: I made the library.

Comment: this best solution, btw

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use when I need custom colors

```
    @NonNull
    public static Snackbar makeSnackbar(@NonNull View layout, @NonNull CharSequence  text, int duration, int backgroundColor, int textColor/*, int actionTextColor*/){
        Snackbar snackBarView = Snackbar.make(layout, text, duration);
        snackBarView.getView().setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        //snackBarView.setActionTextColor(actionTextColor);
        TextView tv = (TextView) snackBarView.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        tv.setTextColor(textColor);
        return snackBarView;
    }
```

And consumed as:

```
CustomView.makeSnackbar(view, "Hello", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG, Color.YELLOW,Color.CYAN).setAction("DO IT", myAction).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to use the dirty and hacky solution with finding TextView in Snackbar by id and you already migrated to androidx, then here's the code:

```
val textViewId = com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
val textView = snackbar.view.findViewById(textViewId) as TextView
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Find by id did't work for me so I found another solution:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, text, duration);//just ordinary creation

ViewGroup snackbarView = (ViewGroup) snackbar.getView();
SnackbarContentLayout contentLayout = (SnackbarContentLayout) snackbarView.getChildAt(0);
TextView tvText = contentLayout.getMessageView();
tvText.setTextColor(/*your color here*/);

//set another colors, show, etc
```

Comment: For me works! There is no the only solution for this problem... Depending on used libraries, themes, styles snackbars can be instantiated in different ways. The clue is to find exactly such one Textview to set it text color. I recommend to use debugger and looking at structure of Snackbar when it is made.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple code that will help to get an instance of both the textview of Snackbar, after that you can call all methods that are applicable on a textview.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make( ... )    // Create Snack bar


snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));  //if you directly want to apply the color to Action Text

TextView snackbarActionTextView = (TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById( android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action );

snackbarActionTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);  //This is another way of doing it

snackbarActionTextView.setTypeface(snackbarActionTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);

//Below Code is to modify the Text in Snack bar
TextView snackbarTextView = (TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
snackbarTextView.setTextSize( 16 );
snackbarTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to save your precious development time, here is the static method I am using:

```
public static void snack(View view, String message) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        TextView tv =  snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text); //snackbar_text
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        snackbar.show();
    }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image: yellow snackbar with black text]

Answer (score 0):

If you are in **Kotlin**, you can create an extension :

```
fun Snackbar.withTextColor(color: Int): Snackbar {
    val tv = this.view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
    tv.setTextColor(color)
    return this
}
```

**Usage** :

```
yourSnackBar.withTextColor(Color.WHITE).show()
```

Comment: same answer as mine 

Answer (score 0):

As per new AndroidX Jitpack components

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Use this extension which i had created

```
inline fun View.snack(message: String, length: Int = Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG,
 f: Snackbar.() -> Unit) {
val snack = Snackbar.make(this, message, length)
snack.f()
snack.show()
}

fun Snackbar.action(action: String, actionColor: Int? = null, textColor: Int? = null, listener: (View) -> Unit) {
setAction(action, listener)
actionColor?.let {
    setActionTextColor(it)
    }
textColor?.let {
    this.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.snackbar_text).setTextColor(it)
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
btn_login.snack(
        getString(R.string.fields_empty_login),
        ContextCompat.getColor(this@LoginActivity, R.color.whiteColor)
    ) {
        action(getString(R.string.text_ok), ContextCompat.getColor(this@LoginActivity, R.color.gray_300),ContextCompat.getColor(this@LoginActivity, R.color.yellow_400)) {
            this@snack.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround to solve this type of problem in `androidx` using `kotlin`

```
 fun showSnackBar(message: String) {
        mContent?.let {
            val snackbar = Snackbar.make(it, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            val snackbarView = snackbar.view
            val tv = snackbarView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.snackbar_text)
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE) //change the color of text
            tv.maxLines = 3 //specify the limit of text line
            snackbar.duration = BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_SHORT //specify the duraction of text message
            snackbar.show()
        }
    }
```

You need initialize `mContent` inside `onViewCreated` method like below

```
var mContent: View? = null
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mContent = view
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Snackbar.make(v, "Loading...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setTextColor(getColor(R.color.orange)).show();
```

Before that I declared my color in **color.xml**

```
<color name="orange">#FF9800</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
Snackbar snackbar;
    snackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.getRoot(), "Hello World!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
    snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.purple_700));
    snackbar.show();

    snackbar.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple_200));
    snackbar.setBackgroundTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple_700));
    snackbar.setAction("Ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

I also noticed the same problem. Thanks to the answers here I've created a small class, which can help to solve this problem in more easily, just by replacing this:

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Error", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

with this:

```
Snackbar2.make(view, "Error", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here is my class:

```
public class Snackbar2 {
static public Snackbar make(View view, int resid, int duration){
    Snackbar result = Snackbar.make(view, resid, duration);
    process(result);
    return result;
}
static public Snackbar make(View view, String text, int duration){
    Snackbar result = Snackbar.make(view, text, duration);
    process(result);
    return result;
}
static private void process(Snackbar snackbar){
    try {
        View view1= snackbar.getView();

        TextView tv = (TextView) view1.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //inform about error
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is a hack, and relies on the id's of various support library views to be static.  I would avoid this solution at all costs.