# How to set Bold text to Android Snackbar Action Text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-snackbar, snackbar

We could set the color for the Action Text of Snackbar using `setActionTextColor` as documented in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html. However, is there a way to make the Text BOLD?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try setting the test to `<b>text</b>`?

Comment: Thanks @iturki. Tried but not working :(

Answer (score 16):

#### Use `snackbar_action` Resource ID.

It turns you that you can use the same method to style the Snackbar's Action text that you use to style the Snackbar's Message text.

You just have to use the Resource ID `snackbar_action` instead of `snackbar_text`.

Here's an example of setting the style for **both** the Message text and the Action text.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make( ... ); // Create the Snackbar however you like.

TextView snackbarActionTextView = (TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById( android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action );
snackbarActionTextView.setTextSize( 20 );
snackbarActionTextView.setTypeface( snackbarActionTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD );

TextView snackbarTextView = (TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById( android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text );
snackbarTextView.setTextSize( 16 );
snackbarTextView.setMaxLines( 3 );
```

In my example, I've set the Action text to have a `TextSize` of 20 and a bold `Typeface`, and the Message text to have a `TextSize` of 16 and allow up to 3 lines.

Comment: For those struggling with alternative for AndroidX,  its `findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_action)`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method to add **BOLD** text to your Snackbar text is to use the [Android Html class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) to generate the text to pass to the Snackbar.make() function. Here is an example:

```
Snackbar.make(view, Html.fromHtml("Add <b>bold</b> to Snackbar text"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

An alternative method is to use the [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) class.

```
SpannableStringBuilder snackbarText = new SpannableStringBuilder();
snackbarText.append("Add ");
int boldStart = snackbarText.length();
snackbarText.append("bold");
snackbarText.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), boldStart, snackbarText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
snackbarText.append(" to Snackbar text");
Snackbar.make(view, snackbarText, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thanks BrentM. This works for the main text, but not for the ACTION text :(. I'm looking for to make the bold text that set through `snackbar.setAction(snackbarActionText, ...);`

Answer (score 1):

With the version **1.1.0** of the [Material Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can define in your app theme the attribute `snackbarButtonStyle`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
  <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/snackbar_button</item>
</style>
```

In this way you can define a custom style for the button used for the Action.
You can change text color, background colore and you can define your custom style for the `textAppearance`.
Something like:

```
  <style name="snackbar_button" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar">
      <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/snackbar_button_textappearance</item>
  </style>

  <style name="snackbar_button_textappearance"  parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to bold the text in snackbar is to given in one of the solutions here, but I will make it more simple:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(yourViewHere, Html.fromHtml("<b>Email Copied To Clipboard</b>"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

 snackbar.show();
```

Comment: `show()` is void, cannot be assigned to snackbar.

Answer (score 0):

The Latest way currently in 2022 is to do this by using **HtmlCompat.fromHtml** not Html.fromHtml:

In Java:

```
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, 
                                      Html.fromHtml("<b>Your text here</b>"), 
                                      Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    snackbar.show();
```

In Kotlin:

```
    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(requireView(),
           HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<b>Your text here</b>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY), 
           Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)

    snackbar.show()
```