# snack bar set action Text always return cap letters

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Snack bar set action text "Retry" always shows in "RETRY"

```
 snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(view, "No internet connection.", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    GlobalBus.getBus().post(new EventbusEvents(""));
                        if(isOnline(context)){
                            snackbar.dismiss();
                        }else {
                            showSnackBar(view,context);
                        }
                    }
                });(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.place_buy));
            snackbar.show();
```

Comment: try to set text from string resource and check it again.

Comment: @HemantParmar I tried but its not working

Comment: `Snackbar snackbar =null;
        TextView textView = (TextView) snackbar.getView();
        textView.setTransformationMethod(null);
        snackbar.setAction(textView.getText(), new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
            }
        });`

try this

Comment: Have your check your styles.xml that parent theme is not set somewhere textAllCaps=true?

Comment: @AntonisRadz have look of Manohar ans.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Material Google Library:

```
TextView snackbarActionTextView = (TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_action);
snackbarActionTextView.setAllCaps(false)
```

And for Support Design Library:

```
TextView snackbarActionTextView = (TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById( android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action );
snackbarActionTextView.setAllCaps(false)
```

some credit goes to  [Joshua Pinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36800101/6478047)

Comment: How to reduce the snack bar height?