# Changing the text of an existing snackBar

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I want to display a snackBar when my token becomes invalid. The snackbar will have an action attached to "Refresh" the token.

```
SnackBar outerSnackBar;

outerSnackBar =  Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, 
"Your request is unauthorized. Please refresh your token", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Refresh"), new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                outerSnackBar.setAction("", null);
                                outerSnackBar.setText("Refreshing");
                                outerSnackBar.show();
   }
}).show();
```

When I click on the snackBar's "Refresh" action button, I want the existing snackBar's text to change to "Refreshing" and the action to display hence this is the code that I have written in the onClickListener.

However, when I click on the "Refresh" action button, the snackbar just dismisses itself.

Is there anyway to modify the text and action of an existing snackbar?

Answer (score 7):

I used to get the view and set the text with this code:

```
TextView snackBarText =  snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text); 
snackBarText.setText("Stackoverflow is cool!");
```

but now using [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) this is the correct way to get the view:

```
TextView snackBarText =  snackbar.getView().findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
```

Comment: Snackbar has already a setText method but no getter, you can get the current text and append on it using this way you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

To only change the text, get the textview of the snackbar:

```
TextView tvSnackbarText =  snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text); 
tvSnackbarText.setText("Any text");
```

You mentioned "... and the action to display", so these shouldn't be necessary:

```
outerSnackBar.setAction("", null);
outerSnackBar.show();
```

Other useful ways are mentioned here [How to set support library snackbar text color to something other than android:textColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31061474/4510869)

Answer (score 2):

Better to show new SnackBar with message "Refreshing"

```
 SnackBar outerSnackBar =  Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, 
    "Your request is unauthorized. Please refresh your token", 
    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Refresh"), new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Snackbar refreshingSnackBar = Snackbar
                                           .make(coordinatorLayout, "Refreshing...",
                                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    refreshingSnackBar.show();
       }
    }).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

### Just use `Snackbar.setText`

There is no need to manually search for the internal text view, which is super hacky.

```
snackbar.setText("New Snackbar Message")
```

It does not seem to dismiss the SnackBar as you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample solution for changing text and color.

```
Snackbar snack = Snakebar.make(parent, "first text", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

//change text when snackbar is showing

snack.setText("new different text")

//change color when snackbar is showing

snack.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green);
```

notice, 'green' color must be define in **colors.xml** file
for example:

```
<color name="green">#4CAF50</color>
```

Comment: True. Important to note is that the snackbar must be showing. If its dismissed and you set text and after that show it, it wont show the text