# Where is the Android Snackbar source code?

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

Where is the source code for `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar`? I can't seem to find it with basic Googling.

I am not looking for instructions on how to use or implement the Snackbar, but rather looking for the source code for the library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there code for Snackbars in Android L or are we expected to implement them ourselves?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633695/is-there-code-for-snackbars-in-android-l-or-are-we-expected-to-implement-them-ou)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For browsing the Android source code on the web, I typically use [the Android GitHub repositories](https://github.com/android). The design library [is located here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget).

You can also clone all of the support libraries via this git repo: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/.

Unfortunately there's one big caveat: The Snackbar (amongst numerous other recent additions to the design support library) doesn't appear to actually be in the repository yet.

Perhaps Google is waiting until the next release to push it, perhaps they are waiting for the release of M, or perhaps they simply forgot. Regardless, that source is simply not publicly available at the moment. I would keep watching the links above for updates though!

---

**EDIT**

The source for Snackbar can now be found in the [support libraries repo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.java).

Comment: Unbelievable! I thought everything that was publicly available as a library was publicly available in the source as well. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it typically is. I've tried to go looking for the design library source a few times recently as well.

Comment: it sucks, but you can get the source if you are using .idea to decompile the .class file.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, Tanis, but I included a link where it can now be found.